# Reactjs - TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem when using the information of a specific item from a JSON of an API.

When wanting to place the fields that I need, it throws the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined -.
```

This happenes when I want to put the field inside

```
return (
*value*
).
```

but if I put it out of the return and show it in console it works.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Platillos_Detalle({ match }) {

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchItem();
    }, []);

    const [items, setItem] = useState({
        item: {}
    });

    const fetchItem = async () => {
        const fetchItem = await fetch(
            `https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/item/get?id=${match.params.id
            }`
        );
        const items = await fetchItem.json();
        setItem(items);
        console.log(items.data.item.description)
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
                <div>{items.data.item.description}</div>
    
        </div>


    )
}
export default Platillos_Detalle;
```

Result of `console.log (items.data.item.description)`

[image]

I'd also like to mention that this same code is used to do something similar but with several items and it works there fine.

#### update 1:

Focus on the "React Hooks useEffect" warning.
As I use a parameter sent from another page (The id of the specific item) I had to define it in: []of useEffect. This solved the warning and now if it received the data from the JSON.
Other problems were because of the JSON structure that looked like this:

JSON example

```
data: {
    itemID: "iditem",
    item: {
        name: "nombre",
        imagen: {
                inforamtion:"url"
        }
    }
}
```

so inside useState add the properties I needed (If I did not do this it would mark the error of
"undefined item") and with that solve the error

```
function Platillos_Detalle({ match }) {

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchItem();
    }, [
        match.params.id
    ]);

    const fetchItem = async () => {
        const fetchItem = await fetch(
            `https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/item/get?id=${match.params.id
            }`
        );
        const item = await fetchItem.json();
        setItem(item.data)
    };
    const [item, setItem] = useState({
        item: {
            images: {

            }
        }
    });
    return (
        <div className="center-block">
            <br />
            <div className="col-md-4 offset-md-4" >
                <div className="card">
                    <img src={item.item.images.information} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title">{item.item.name} </h5>
                        <p className="card-text">{item.item.description}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-footer ">
                        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Pedir :v</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br></br>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Platillos_Detalle;
```

Answer (score 2):

It’s probably not yet ready since its the result of the async code. Maybe try adding a condition checking if it exists.

```
Items.data ? Items .data.anything : []
```

Comment: that helped me to see that I had to focus on the useEffects warning, and it is already correct.   look at the update